# Cross compile a raspberry pi kernel

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, cross-compilation

I've been trying for the past few hours to cross compile a rpi kernel on my Arch Linux distro and then my Ubuntu distro when that failed, I received similar errors for both attempts.

I'm currently following these guides: http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation
http://ozzmaker.com/2012/11/26/how-to-cross-compile-the-kernel-for-the-raspberry-pi/

I have a folder in my home directory called "linux". Inside this is a folder named tools and rpi-3.6.y, these contain compilation tools and the rpi kernel source, respectively.

When I reach the "Firstly, ensure your build directory is clean" step and run

```
make mrproper
```

I get the following error:

```
scripts/Makefile.clean:17: /home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/arch/x86/crypto/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/arch/x86/crypto/Makefile'. Stop.
scripts/Makefile.clean:94: recipe for target 'arch/x86/crypto' failed
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/crypto] Error 2
Makefile:1039: recipe for target '_clean_arch/x86' failed
make: *** [_clean_arch/x86] Error 2
```

I decided to skip this and move onto the actual cross-compilation and I get this error:

```
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} oldconfig

/bin/sh: /home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/scripts/kconfig/lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh: No such file or directory
scripts/kconfig/conf --oldconfig Kconfig
arch/arm/Kconfig:945: can't open file "arch/arm/mach-mvebu/Kconfig"
/home/aquacell/linux/rpi-3.6.y/scripts/kconfig/Makefile:33: recipe for target 'oldconfig' failed
make[1]: *** [oldconfig] Error 1
Makefile:503: recipe for target 'oldconfig' failed
make: *** [oldconfig] Error 2
```

Can anyone provide any insight as to what I might be doing wrong? I feel like there is a very obvious step or crucial part not listed that I am missing, as I can't find any information on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you aren't using the [official documentation from the Arch-ARM devs](http://archlinuxarm.org/developers/distcc-cross-compiling)?

Comment: I am trying to Cross-compile to Raspbian, not ALARM. Can this be used for Raspbian? In the mean time, I'll try this out on my ALARM pi. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Oh, I only saw the [tag:arch-linux] and [tag:raspberry-pi] tags... You should edit your question and make that explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i look at the latest commit of 3.6.y (https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.6.y) these files are present - try downloading the source again or check the permissions on the files.

When i compiled my last kernel on Debian i had to move the source directory to /usr/src/rpi-kernel for some reason, but i could not get it to work in my home directory.

if permissions are not the problem maybe you want to use a newer version of the kernel, github looks like 3.12.y is current.

Comment: I tried this as well. These are the ONLY steps I did on the following: 1) Download kernel source. 2) Unpack source and place in /usr/bin/ and rename it rpi-kernel 3) Download cross-compile tools (mentioned in original question) to /home/me/linux/tools/. 4) Call make mrproper. Error thrown. Note: I did choose to download the zips and unpack them that way rather than the tarballs. I can't imagine that affecting anything, but you never know.

Comment: these files what make is complaining about, are they really missing? btw: i used git and i often had problems with large zip files on linux in the past - could be worth investigating...

Comment: i just had to know... and downloaded the zip file. while unzipping i got some 'File name too long' errors. so my advice: try the tarballs :)